# How to use "allow-add"

Tags: symfony

I have my form that works very well, but I would like to use "allow_add" to be able to upload another file.
I was wondering how to use it, because this is the first time I use it.

Here are my two form and my type:
UserType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname',TextType::class)
        ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('fichiers', CollectionType::class, array(
            'type' => new UserFileType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'data' => array(new UserFile())))
    ;
}
```

UserFileType:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('documentFile', 'file',array(
        'label' => 'Uploader'
    ))
    ;
}
```

View:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="add-user-form-input">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    {{ form_widget(form.firstname,{'attr': {'placeholder': 'Nom'}})}}
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    {{ form_widget(form.lastname,{'attr': {'placeholder': 'Prénom', 'class' : 'last-input'}})}}
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    {{ form_widget(form.email,{'attr': {'placeholder': 'Email', 'class' : 'last-input'}})}}
                </div>                   

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    {% for fichier in form.fichiers %}
                        {{ form_row(fichier.documentFile) }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    {{ form_widget(form.save,{'attr': { 'class' : 'add-user-upload-one'}})}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

I thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/add-new-collection-prototype

I think that's exactly what you're looking for ;)

It's nice enough when you customize it properly

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the file using Symfony's built in FileType ([How to upload files in symfony)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html).

You should be able to do something like:

```
->add('fichiers', FileType::class, array(
     'multiple' => true
))
```

Not sure if you need your custom form type for some other reason, but this works quite well if you do not.